# Подключение PhpMorhpy в класс

Tags: php, ооп

Работаю с библиотекой PhpMorhpy. К ней прилагается следующий пример инициализации:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../src/common.php');

// set some options
$opts = array(
// storage type, follow types supported
// PHPMORPHY_STORAGE_FILE - use file operations(fread, fseek) for dictionary access, this is very slow...
// PHPMORPHY_STORAGE_SHM - load dictionary in shared memory(using shmop php extension), this is preferred mode
// PHPMORPHY_STORAGE_MEM - load dict to memory each time when phpMorphy intialized, this useful when shmop ext. not activated. Speed same as for PHPMORPHY_STORAGE_SHM type
'storage' => PHPMORPHY_STORAGE_FILE,
// Extend graminfo for getAllFormsWithGramInfo method call
'with_gramtab' => false,
// Enable prediction by suffix
'predict_by_suffix' => true, 
// Enable prediction by prefix
'predict_by_db' => true
);

// Path to directory where dictionaries located
$dir = dirname(__FILE__) . '/phpmorphy-0.3.7/dicts';

// Create descriptor for dictionary located in $dir directory with russian language
$dict_bundle = new phpMorphy_FilesBundle($dir, 'rus');

// Create phpMorphy instance
try {
$morphy = new phpMorphy($dict_bundle, $opts);
} catch(phpMorphy_Exception $e) {
die('Error occured while creating phpMorphy instance: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Я пишу свой класс, который работает с PhpMorphy. Ранее данную инициализацию я проводила в начале каждой функции класса. Понимаю, что это не правильно, поэтому хочу оптимизировать работу кода. Как правильно инициализировать phpMorphy внутри класса?

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужен один экзэмпляр класса то можно сделать через гетер;

```
private $morph = null;

public function getMorph() 
{
   if(!is_null($this->morph) {
       return $this->morph;
   }

   // set some options
   $opts = array(
   // storage type, follow types supported
   // PHPMORPHY_STORAGE_FILE - use file operations(fread, fseek) for dictionary access, this is very slow...
   // PHPMORPHY_STORAGE_SHM - load dictionary in shared memory(using shmop php extension), this is preferred mode
   // PHPMORPHY_STORAGE_MEM - load dict to memory each time when phpMorphy intialized, this useful when shmop ext. not activated. Speed same as for PHPMORPHY_STORAGE_SHM type
  'storage' => PHPMORPHY_STORAGE_FILE,
  // Extend graminfo for getAllFormsWithGramInfo method call
  'with_gramtab' => false,
  // Enable prediction by suffix 
  'predict_by_suffix' => true, 
  // Enable prediction by prefix
  'predict_by_db' => true
  );

  // Path to directory where dictionaries located
  $dir = dirname(__FILE__) . '/phpmorphy-0.3.7/dicts';

  // Create descriptor for dictionary located in $dir directory with russian language
  $dict_bundle = new phpMorphy_FilesBundle($dir, 'rus');

  // Create phpMorphy instance
  try {
    $morphy = new phpMorphy($dict_bundle, $opts);
  } catch(phpMorphy_Exception $e) {
    die('Error occured while creating phpMorphy instance: ' . $e->getMessage());
  }

}
```

или в конструктуре класса

```
public function __construct() 
{

   // set some options
   $opts = array(
   // storage type, follow types supported
   // PHPMORPHY_STORAGE_FILE - use file operations(fread, fseek) for   dictionary access, this is very slow...
   // PHPMORPHY_STORAGE_SHM - load dictionary in shared memory(using shmop php extension), this is preferred mode
   // PHPMORPHY_STORAGE_MEM - load dict to memory each time when phpMorphy intialized, this useful when shmop ext. not activated. Speed same as for PHPMORPHY_STORAGE_SHM type
  'storage' => PHPMORPHY_STORAGE_FILE,
   // Extend graminfo for getAllFormsWithGramInfo method call
  'with_gramtab' => false,
  // Enable prediction by suffix
  'predict_by_suffix' => true, 
  // Enable prediction by prefix
  'predict_by_db' => true
  );

  // Path to directory where dictionaries located
  $dir = dirname(__FILE__) . '/phpmorphy-0.3.7/dicts';

  // Create descriptor for dictionary located in $dir directory with russian language
  $dict_bundle = new phpMorphy_FilesBundle($dir, 'rus');

  // Create phpMorphy instance
  try {
    $this->morph = new phpMorphy($dict_bundle, $opts);
  } catch(phpMorphy_Exception $e) {
    die('Error occured while creating phpMorphy instance: ' . $e->getMessage());
  }
}
```

Как использовать? первый вариант если выы делаете геттером обварачивая в какойто класс то это будет типо

```
$myMorph = new MyMorph();
$moph = $myMorph->getMorph();
```

во втором случае вам придёться инициализировать в конструкторе каждого класса и получать класс через `$this`

```
$this->morph;
```

Comment: А куда вписывать это: require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../src/common.php');

в класс или до?

Comment: @RenaNip либо в начале файла либо в файле автолодера если есть. на чём проэкт?

Comment: пока полностью на php, будет переносится на фреймворк

Comment: @RenaNip Надо посмотреть на структуру вообще по уму нужен автолодер для таких целей, точка входа index.php или страница отдельный фаил?

Comment: пока отдельный файл. структура такова -- скрипт подгружает мой класс через require, а мой класс так же подгружает phpMorphy

Comment: @RenaNip Пока лучше подгружать так.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!